# Unable to create mocks on post request with content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: rest, testing, mocking, mountebank

I am working with mountebank to create mocks for an External REST API
which is a POST request with `content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The API is of format

`https://<url>/dpay/MPmt`

and data payload is passed in format `msg=01223~20170607114321~ABC~12345~NA~NA`

I have to search on the basis of `~ABC~12345~` which would remain constant.

I have used **contains, matches and equals** predicates but was not able to run them while passing the payload in request body.

However, I was able to get it running when passing payload as a query parameter

`https://url/dpay/MPmt?msg=01223~20170607114321~ABC~12345~NA~NA`

but can't find a way to get it done when passed in request body.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the predicate "contains" and pass your matching string only. What I suspect is that you are using

"contains" : 
{ "body" : { 
   "msg": "~ABC~12345~"
  }
 }

this will look for an msg variable in the request body, instead, use

"contains" : {"body": "~ABC~12345~"}

and it will match it directly in your request body.

I faced the same issue, Hope it works for you.